# Call ASP.NET web service from a different domain via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I want to call an asp.net web service's from a different domain with javascript.

Ex :

I have the site "www.abc.com", I want it to call the web service on "www.xyz.com" with some javascript I load from X domain.

First I add the script with this :

```
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=%27http://myscript.com/script.js%27 type=%27text/javascript%27%3E%3C/script%3E"));
```

This is the `script.js` file :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://www.xyz.com/Service1.asmx/InsertIt",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: OnSuccess,
  error: function (response) {
      alert(response);
  }
});

function OnSuccess(response) {
  alert(response.d);
}
```

I know Cross-domain calls from within client-side code are a no-no in all major browsers. To achieve that, I think you can use CORS.

> Use CORS, ie. set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to
>   http://your-caller-domain.com in the web

In this example, I know the caller domain : www.abc.com. but in the real life, I will never know the caller domain. I know there's other way to do a Cross-Domain call, ex : JSONP. But this technique is really complexe (for me).

So I am asking is there's an easy way to achieve a Cross-Domain call ?

Comment: You've already mention JSONP. AFAIK, using JSONP in JQuery is very similar with the code you provide (see https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and safest method is using your server side framework to do your http requests which you can then present to your JS. This negates any cross browser annoyances that client side calls inherit.

Eg:

- AJAX hits `www.abc.com/getdata.ashx`.
- Execute your request to `www.xyz.com` using below method.
- Return a json string or plain text. It's up to you.

[WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for .NET. There is an example at the bottom.
Also look at HTTP handlers (.ashx) for doing requests. Not essential, but it's good to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation bellow, u'll be able to perform cross-domain requests

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
   $.getJSON( "http://www.xyz.com/Service1.asmx/InsertIt", function( data ) {
    alert(data.d);
   });
```